# Adding Ids or Classes to XSL

Tags: css, xml, styles, xslt

I'm trying to add ids or classes to the following attachment below (for each yellow section). I've found the "date", "title", and "more" class, but I'm have trouble seeiong body, img, category and published sections.Click the link to see the output....

[blog pic](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/31vv5)

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl ddwrt msxsl rssaggwrt" 
               xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
               xmlns:rssaggwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/rssagg/runtime"
               xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
               xmlns:rssFeed="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:RSSAggregatorWebPart"
               xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
               xmlns:rss1="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
               xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"
               xmlns:atom2="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">
  <xsl:param name="rss_FeedLimit">5</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="rss_ExpandFeed">false</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="rss_LCID">1033</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="rss_WebPartID">RSS_Viewer_WebPart</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="rss_alignValue">left</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="rss_IsDesignMode">True</xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="rss">
    <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate"/>

  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF">
    <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate"/>

  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="atom:feed">
    <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate"/>

  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="atom2:feed">
    <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate"/>

  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="channel/item"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
    <div class="slm-layout-main" >
      <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.body">
        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>

        <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>

      </xsl:call-template>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
    <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
      <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
      <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
      <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
      <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
        <div class="item link-item postSection" > <a class="postHeaderLink" href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" > <xsl:value-of select="title"/> </a>
          <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
            <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
              <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>

              <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
            <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
              <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>

              <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
    <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
    <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="{$rss_alignValue}" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
      <div class="postDate">
        <xsl:choose>
          <!-- some RSS2.0 contain pubDate tag, some others dc:date -->
          <xsl:when test="string-length(pubDate) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:variable name="pubDateLength" select="string-length(pubDate) - 3" />
            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(substring(pubDate,0,$pubDateLength),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(dc:date),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </div>
      <xsl:if test="string-length(description) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
        <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
          <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="description"/>

        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <div class="description"> <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(link))}">More...</a> </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="RDFMainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="rss1:item"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
    <div class="slm-layout-main" >
      <div class="groupheader item medium"> <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(rss1:channel/rss1:link))}"> <xsl:value-of select="rss1:channel/rss1:title"/> </a> </div>
      <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate.body">
        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>

        <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>

      </xsl:call-template>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="RDFMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
    <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
      <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
      <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
      <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
      <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
        <div class="item link-item postSection" > <a class="postHeaderLink" href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" > <xsl:value-of select="rss1:title"/> </a>
          <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
            <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate.description">
              <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>

              <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
            <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate.description">
              <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>

              <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="RDFMainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
    <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
    <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="{$rss_alignValue}" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};"> <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(dc:date),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
      <xsl:if test="string-length(rss1:description) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
        <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
          <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="rss1:description"/>

        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <div class="description"> <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(rss1:link))}">More...</a> </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="ATOMMainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="atom:entry"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
    <div class="slm-layout-main" >
      <div class="groupheader item medium"> <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom:link/@href))}"> <xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/> </a> </div>
      <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate.body">
        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>

        <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>

      </xsl:call-template>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="ATOMMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
    <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
      <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
      <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
      <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
      <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
        <div class="item link-item postSection" > <a class="postHeaderLink" href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" > <xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/> </a>
          <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
            <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate.description">
              <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>

              <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
            <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate.description">
              <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>

              <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="ATOMMainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
    <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
    <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="{$rss_alignValue}" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};"> <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(atom:updated),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
      <div class="postDate">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="string-length(atom:summary) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
            <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
              <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom:summary"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="string-length(atom:content) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
            <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
              <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom:content"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </div>
      <div class="description"> <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom:link/@href))}">More...</a> </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="ATOM2MainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="atom2:entry"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
    <div class="slm-layout-main" >
      <div class="groupheader item medium"> <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom2:link/@href))}"> <xsl:value-of select="atom2:title"/> </a> </div>
      <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.body">
        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>

        <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>

      </xsl:call-template>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
    <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
      <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
      <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
      <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
      <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
        <div class="item link-item postSection" > <a class="postHeaderLink" href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" > <xsl:value-of select="atom2:title"/> </a>
          <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
            <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.description">
              <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>

              <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
            <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.description">
              <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>

              <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
    <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
    <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="{$rss_alignValue}" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};"> <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(atom2:updated),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
      <div class="postDate">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="string-length(atom2:summary) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
            <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
              <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom2:summary"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="string-length(atom2:content) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
            <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
              <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom2:content"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </div>
      <div class="description"> <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom2:link/@href))}">More...</a> </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="GetSafeHtml">
    <xsl:param name="Html"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$rss_IsDesignMode = 'True'">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Html"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="rssaggwrt:MakeSafe($Html)"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the output in HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox">
  <div class="ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read 5b3f0d13-9a94-4cb5-8d0b-09bcd8a3bfe4" id="div_5b3f0d13-9a94-4cb5-8d0b-09bcd8a3bfe4">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" class="s4-wpcell-plain" id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" class="s4-wpTopTable">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr class="ms-WPHeader">
                          <td align="left" class="ms-wpTdSpace">&nbsp;</td>
                          <td class="ms-WPHeaderTd" id="WebPartTitleWPQ7" title="Latest News! - Displays an RSS feed."><h3 class="ms-standardheader ms-WPTitle" style="text-align:justify;"><a href="*******Can't show this link*******News/default.aspx" accesskey="W"><nobr><span>Latest News!</span><span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ7"></span></nobr></a></h3></td>
                          <td align="right" onclick="OpenWebPartMenu('WebPartWPQ7_Menu', this, 'WebPartWPQ7','False'); TrapMenuClick(event); return false;" class="ms-WPHeaderTdMenu"><span style="display:none;">
                            <menu class="ms-SrvMenuUI" id="WebPartWPQ7_Menu">
                              <ie:menuitem type="option" text="Minimize" onmenuclick="javascript:MSOLayout_MinimizeRestore(MenuWebPart)" id="MSOMenu_Minimize" title="Collapse this web part."> </ie:menuitem>
                              <ie:menuitem type="option" text="Restore" onmenuclick="javascript:MSOLayout_MinimizeRestore(MenuWebPart)" id="MSOMenu_Restore" title="Expand this web part."> </ie:menuitem>
                              <ie:menuitem type="option" text="Close" onmenuclick="javascript:MSOLayout_RemoveWebPart(MenuWebPart)" id="MSOMenu_Close" title="Close this Web Part. You can still find it under closed Web Parts section in the insert ribbon. These changes will apply to all users."> </ie:menuitem>
                              <ie:menuitem type="option" text="Delete" onmenuclick="if(confirm('You are about to permanently delete this Web Part. Are you sure you want to do this?')) {MSOWebPartPage_partDeleted = MenuWebPartID;MSOWebPartPage_MenuDoPostBack('ctl00$m', MenuWebPartID + ';MSOMenu_Delete');}" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/DelItem.gif" id="MSOMenu_Delete" title="Delete this Web Part from the page. These changes will apply to all users."> </ie:menuitem>
                              <ie:menuitem type="separator"></ie:menuitem>
                              <ie:menuitem type="option" text="Edit Web Part" onmenuclick="javascript:MSOTlPn_ShowToolPane2Wrapper('Edit', 16, MenuWebPartID)" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/EditItem.gif" id="MSOMenu_Edit" title="Change properties of this shared Web Part. These changes will apply to all users."> </ie:menuitem>
                              <ie:menuitem type="option" text="Connections" onmenuclick="" id="MSOMenu_Connections" title="Show connections options for this Web Part. These changes will apply to all users."> </ie:menuitem>
                              <ie:menuitem type="separator"></ie:menuitem>
                              <ie:menuitem type="option" text="Export..." onmenuclick="javascript:MSOWebPartPage_ExportCheckWarning('\u002fsites\u002fdermres\u002f_vti_bin\u002fexportwp.aspx?pageurl=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fdermdev2\u00253A80\u00252Fsites\u00252Fdermres\u00252FSitePages\u00252FHome\u00252Easpx\u0026guidstring='+ escape(MenuWebPartID), MenuWebPart.getAttribute('HasPers') == 'true')" id="MSOMenu_Export" title="Export this Web Part. These changes will apply to all users."> </ie:menuitem>
                              <ie:menuitem style="display:none" type="option" text="Help" onmenuclick="MSOWebPartPage_SetNewWindowLocation(MenuWebPart.getAttribute('helpLink'), MenuWebPart.getAttribute('helpMode'))" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/HelpIcon.gif" id="MSOMenu_Help"> </ie:menuitem>
                            </menu>
                            </span>
                            <div onmouseover="this.className='ms-WPMenuDivHover'" onmouseout="this.className='ms-WPMenuDiv'" class="ms-WPMenuDiv"><a menuid="WebPartWPQ7_Menu" onfocus="UpdateWebPartMenuFocus(this, 'ms-wpselectlinkfocus', 'ms-WPEditTextVisible');" onblur="UpdateWebPartMenuFocus(this, 'ms-wpselectlink', 'ms-WPEditText');" class="ms-wpselectlink" title="Latest News! Web Part Menu" href="#" onkeydown="WebPartMenuKeyboardClick(document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ7_MenuLink'), 13, 40, event)" id="WebPartWPQ7_MenuLink" onclick="OpenWebPartMenuFromLink('WebPartWPQ7_Menu', this, 'WebPartWPQ7','False'); return false;"><img style="border-width:0px;" alt="Latest News! Web Part Menu" src="/_layouts/images/wpmenuarrow.png" class="ms-WPHeaderMenuImg"></a></div></td>
                          <td class="ms-WPHeaderTdSelection"><span class="ms-WPHeaderTdSelSpan">
                            <input type="checkbox" onclick="TrapMenuClick(event); return false;" onmouseup="WpCbxSelect(event); return false;" onkeyup="WpCbxKeyHandler(event);" onfocus="this.className='ms-WPHeaderCbxVisible'" onblur="this.className='ms-WPHeaderCbxHidden'" title="Select or deselect Latest News! Web Part" class="ms-WPHeaderCbxHidden" id="SelectionCbxWebPartWPQ7">
                            </span></td>
                          <td align="left" class="ms-wpTdSpace">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class=""><div style="" allowdelete="false" allowremove="false" class="ms-WPBody noindex ms-wpContentDivSpace" width="100%" id="WebPartWPQ7" haspers="false" webpartid2="5b3f0d13-9a94-4cb5-8d0b-09bcd8a3bfe4" webpartid="4925e295-451f-4c05-8411-a3d05fbed1c1">
                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td><div style="padding-top:5px;" id="rssFeedWPDiv_ctl00_m_g_5b3f0d13_9a94_4cb5_8d0b_09bcd8a3bfe4">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
                                        <div xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:rssfeed="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:RSSAggregatorWebPart" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rss1="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:atom2="http://purl.org/atom/ns#" class="slm-layout-main">
                                          <div class="item link-item"><a href="javascript:ToggleItemDescription('g_5b3f0d13_9a94_4cb5_8d0b_09bcd8a3bfe41')">Happy Hippos!</a>
                                            <div align="left" style="display:block; text-align:left;" class="description" id="g_5b3f0d13_9a94_4cb5_8d0b_09bcd8a3bfe41">Friday, January 20, 2012
                                              -
                                              <div class="postDescription"><b></b>
                                                <div class="ExternalClass7307B3207C5F4D249548C7AF6EAFC3D5">
                                                  <p class="postImage">&#8203;<img style="margin:5px;width:233px;height:178px" src="*******Can't show this link*******News/Lists/Photos/HappyHippo.JPG" alt="HappyHippo.JPG"></p>
                                                  <p>Happy Hippos!</p>
                                                  <p>Vestibulum ante ip<span style="text-decoration:underline">sum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices pos</span>uere
                                                    cubilia Curae; Aliquam ac lorem nisi. Aliquam vitae lacus sapien. Nam 
                                                    ornare, tellus id tristique <strong>elementum, ipsum velit gravida elit, vitae 
                                                    condimentum neque ante tincidunt est. Nulla facilisi. Sed</strong> pulvinar neque
                                                    vitae dolor pretium gravida. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique 
                                                    senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.&nbsp;</p>
                                                  <p>writing more.......................<br>
                                                    <br>
                                                  </p>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="postCategory"><b>Posted In:</b> <a href="*******Can't show this link*******_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={E1ED84A3-3668-4A94-B5A8-4F8EE21F6759}&amp;ID=6&amp;RootFolder=*">Announcements</a>; <a href="*******Can't show this link*******_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={E1ED84A3-3668-4A94-B5A8-4F8EE21F6759}&amp;ID=5&amp;RootFolder=*">Current Issues</a>; <a href="*******Can't show this link*******_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={E1ED84A3-3668-4A94-B5A8-4F8EE21F6759}&amp;ID=7&amp;RootFolder=*">Lastest News</a>; <a href="*******Can't show this link*******_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={E1ED84A3-3668-4A94-B5A8-4F8EE21F6759}&amp;ID=4&amp;RootFolder=*">What's New?</a></div>
                                              <div></div>
                                              <div class="description"><a href="*******Can't show this link*******Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=7">More...</a></div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </div></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="display:none" id="vid_5b3f0d13-9a94-4cb5-8d0b-09bcd8a3bfe4"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, this is code from the RSS viewer XSL in Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

the html representation of the content will be generated on-the-fly by proprietary extensions to the xslt processor (mainly `rssaggwrt:MakeSafe` which operates on parts of the feed content). if you can't configure or tweak with the extension library you might have to follow a strategy like:

- let the browser render the page
- apply your xslt ops on the innermost html element containing rss feed content. this may involve serializing the content (eg. using jquery property `innerHTML`), normalizing content to valid xml, re-parsing.
- replace the original dom subtree with the transform output

if you only wish to annotate dom elements with classes you're probably better off with a jquery handler operating on the output of the original stylesheet.

Comment: @user952851: to do so i need a sample page of the xslt output or verbal info about the html representation of the content you wish to add ids/classes to.

Comment: OK I've updated the post. Thank you for helping me on this. XSL is not my strongest areas.

Comment: As shown in the blog pic above of the post, I wanted to wrap ids or class around those areas.